# Loading existing HTML file with JSDOM for frontend unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai, jsdom

I'm new to unit testing, and I'm aware my tests may not be valuable or following a specific best practice, but I'm focused on getting this working, which will allow me to test my frontend code using JSDOM.

```
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');
const { describe, it, beforeEach } = require('mocha');
const { expect } = require('chai');

let checkboxes;
const options = {
  contentType: 'text/html',
};

describe('component.js', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    JSDOM.fromFile('/Users/johnsoct/Dropbox/Development/andybeverlyschool/dist/individual.html', options).then((dom) => {
      checkboxes = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    });
  });
  describe('checkboxes', () => {
    it('Checkboxes should be an array', () => {
      expect(checkboxes).to.be.a('array');
    });
  });
});
```

I'm getting the error "AssertionError: expected undefined to be an array". I'm simply using the array test as a test to ensure I have JSDOM functioning correctly. There are no other errors occurring. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've narrowed down the issue to - beforeEach isn't finished before my checkboxes test runs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`fromFile`](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom#fromfile) is an async function, meaning that by the time your `beforeEach()` has finished and the tests start running, it is (probably) still loading the file.

[Mocha handles async code](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code) in two ways: either return a promise or pass in a callback. So either return the promise from `fromFile` or do this:

```
beforeEach(function(done) {
    JSDOM.fromFile(myFile)
    .then((dom) => {
      checkboxes = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    })
    .then(done, done);
});
```

The promise version looks like this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    return JSDOM.fromFile(myFile)
    .then((dom) => {
      checkboxes = dom.window.document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    });
});
```