# JSDOM - Document is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom, jsdom

I've created a very simple page that just displays a single message, as I'm trying to test out the JSDOM to use `document`. However, I'm getting the below error.

First of all, I have seen the countless examples online, in addition to the questions posted on Stack Overflow, but I have not been able to resolve even the simplest example. As a side-note, I am new to Javascript.

My code so far is as follows:

Root Directory

--->index.html
--->module.js
--->package-lock.json
--->package.json
--->test
--->--->messageTest.js

The different files are as follows:

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jsdom Unit Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id='msg'>Hello, World!</p>
  <script src="module.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**module.js**

```
function updateMsg(newMsg) {
  document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = newMsg;
}

updateMsg("Changing message");

module.exports = updateMsg;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "message-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Testing how to use the JSDOM",
  "main": "module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^15.1.1",
    "mocha": "^6.2.0",
    "mocha-jsdom": "^2.0.0",
    "rewire": "^4.0.1",
    "sinon": "^7.3.2"
  }
}
```

**messageTest.js**

```
var updateMsg = require('../module.js');
const expect = require('chai').expect
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

describe('updateMsg', function () {

  before(function() {
    return JSDOM.fromFile('index.html')
      .then((dom) => {
        global.window = dom.window;
        global.document = window.document;
      });
  })

  it ('updates the innerHTML of element with id "msg"', function () {
    expect(document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML).to.equal('Hello, World!');
    updateMsg('The new msg!');
    expect(document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML).to.equal('The new msg!');
  });
});
```

If I run the test with `npm test`, I get the `ReferenceError: document is not defined` error at the `document.getElementByID...` step in the **module.js** file.

If I remove the `updateMsg("Changing message")`, my test obviously runs fine.

Comment: Your code seems to run well, it display the text "Changing message" in the <p/> tag, check fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7k96oeuw/
And, its not `document.getElementByID` like you describe it, is `document.getElementById`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45961549/2444210

Comment: Thanks for the catch. My code runs fine indeed (on a physical browser) but when I run the test where the browser needs to be simulated, I get that the document element is not found. This should be simulated with JSDOM (as far as I understand), but I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in that example:

1. You're mixing jsdom window and global node context. Avoid assigning to `global` (because that's making it easier to make that mistake), don't `require()` scripts that you want to run in your virtual window.
2. jsdom prevents running on-page scripts by default, so your module.js is neither loaded nor executed. You'll have to provide `{ resources: "usable", runScripts: "outside-only" }` parameters to fix that (make sure you read about the security implications in the [jsdom README](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts)).
3. You're not waiting for the `load` event, so your test is run before jsdom has a chance to load the script.

Working code would look something like this:

```
const expect = require("chai").expect;
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");

describe("updateMsg", function() {
  let jsdom;
  before(async function() {
    jsdom = await JSDOM.fromFile("index.html", {
      resources: "usable",
      runScripts: "dangerously"
    });
    await new Promise(resolve =>
      jsdom.window.addEventListener("load", resolve)
    );
  });

  it('updates the innerHTML of element with id "msg"', function() {
    expect(jsdom.window.document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML).to.equal(
      "Hello, World!"
    );
    jsdom.window.updateMsg("The new msg!");
    expect(jsdom.window.document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML).to.equal(
      "The new msg!"
    );
  });
});
```

You'll also need to remove the module line from module.js, `module` doesn't exist in the browser.

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! It's resolved the error. Could you just let me know how the updateMsg("") function is accessible from the test file even though I've removed the module line from module.js?

Comment: @Adam jsdom actually works like a real browser - it has it's own script loading mechanism that issues HTTP requests (or local file loads that don't use node's module resolution mechanism), so your script-src tag triggers the proper loading and makes your function available.

This also means other node internals (require, modules, etc) are not available! It does give you a "perfect" browser to test with - which also means if you want module resolution, you'll have to resort to webpacking and again loading your script with a proper tag.